# Proving a combinatoric identity

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

Prove

$\sum_{k\geq 0}^{\infty }\binom{n}{3k}=(2^n+m)/3$,

where m=where m depends on n and is equal to $2, 1, −1, −2, −1, 1,$ when n is congruent to
$0,1,2,3,4,5$ ($\mod 6$) respectively.
and

$\sum_{k\geq 0}^{\infty }\binom{n}{4k}=\frac{2^n+m2^{\left \lceil \frac{n}{2} \right \rceil}}{4}$

where $m = 2,1,0,−1,−2,−1,0,1,$ when $n\ge1$ is congruent, respectively,

to
$0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7$ ($\mod 8$).

And if possible, prove

$\sum_{k\geq 0}^{\infty }\binom{n}{rk}=  \frac{1}{r}\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}(1+w^j)^n$

where $w=e^{2\pi i/r}$.
This is an assigment that our teacher tell us to do. However the only clue that he gives us is to use binomial theorem... Don't really know how to do that. I can only use direct counting to prove$\sum_{k\geq 0}^{\infty }\binom{n}{3k}=(2^n+m)/3$ but starting form $k=4$ the case gets a lot complicated. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Could you format it better? It is really difficult to read in among the text.

Comment: ok thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Look up multisection of series. Combine with $(1+x)^n = $... well you know.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what does the page says. I understand the generating function part but was confused by the S(n,j) part-- can u help explain it?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\omega$ be a third root of unity, then 
$1^k + \omega^k + \omega^{2k}$ is $3$ if $k$ is divisible by 3, and $0$ otherwise. Hence:

$3 \sum \binom{n}{3k} = \sum \binom{n}{k} 1^k + \sum \binom{n}{k} \omega^k + \sum \binom{n}{k} (\omega^2)^k$

Now use the binomial theorem to evaluate those three sums.  The other exercise can be done in the same way (this time, use 4 sums, with $1^k$, $i^k$, $(-1)^k$, and $(-i)^k$).

Comment: The RHS (summing over all $k$) is OK because the terms where $k$ is not divisible by $3$ cancel out (see first line in the answer).